# Finding $\int \ln (\cos x) \sin^{-2} x \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to find $\int \ln(\cos x) \sin^{-2} x \, dx$.

I integrated by parts ($\ln (\cos x) = u$ and $\sin x\,dx = dv$) and got $-(\cos x) \ln(\cos x)+\cos x+c$. Is that correct?

I just need to know if the solution is correct?

Comment: Differentiate your proposed answer. That will answer your question in the negative.

Comment: Your $dv$ should be $\sin^{-2}xdx$. This is integration by parts, not $u$-substitution!

Answer (score 1):

Not correct as

$$\int\frac{\ln (\cos x)}{\sin^2x}dx$$

$$=\ln (\cos x)\cdot\int\csc^2xdx-\int\left(\frac{d\ \ln (\cos x)}{dx}\cdot\int\csc^2xdx\right)dx$$

$$=\ln (\cos x)\cdot(-\cot x)-\int\left(\frac{-\sin x}{\cos x }\cdot(-\cot x)\right)dx$$

$$=\ln (\cos x)\cdot(-\cot x)-\int dx=\cdots $$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use integration by parts let dv = sin^-2(x) dx and u = ln(cosx)

Notice the integral of sin^-2(x) is -cot(x) hence v = -cot(x). and u' = -tan.

Can you finish it from there ?

Comment: Good answer, but you should use $\LaTeX$ to format your mathematical statements: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Will do. Thanks